# Android StackOverflowError on Kindle devices

Tags: android, kindle, stack-overflow

I have created 2 versions of my app, one with and one without ads.  I have used a library that contains pretty much the whole paid app.  The free version extends the base library's HomeScreenActivity and starts its own MainActivity when a button is clicked.

The app works fine on my devices and emulators, but, according to Amazon, it fails to start on Kindle devices.  It would be great if there was an emulator that I could use to test it on, but they no longer have an emulator.  They have sent me the following logs, but I am not able to figure out what is causing this loop.

```
06-02 07:46:46.429: I/ActivityStack(203): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 pkg=com.myandroidapps.thegamefree 

cmp=com.myandroidapps.thegamefree/.HomeScreenActivity} from pid 559
06-02 07:46:46.429: V/ActivityStack(203): Prepare open transition: starting ActivityRecord{41bfc198 com.myandroidapps.thegamefree/.HomeScreenActivity}
06-02 07:46:46.484: V/ActivityStack(203): Prepare open transition: prev=ActivityRecord{418e8ae0 com.amazon.kindle.otter/.Launcher}
06-02 07:46:46.515: I/ActivityManager(203): Start proc com.myandroidapps.thegamefree for activity com.myandroidapps.thegamefree/.HomeScreenActivity: pid=2425 uid=10051 gids={3003}
06-02 07:46:46.578: D/dalvikvm(203): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1325K, 50% free 16569K/32903K, paused 2ms+7ms
06-02 07:46:46.672: I/dalvikvm(2425): Could not find method android.content.Context.startActivities, referenced from method android.support.v4.a.a.a
06-02 07:46:46.672: W/dalvikvm(2425): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 136: Landroid/content/Context;.startActivities ([Landroid/content/Intent;Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
06-02 07:46:46.672: D/dalvikvm(2425): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0007
06-02 07:46:46.687: I/dalvikvm(2425): threadid=1: stack overflow on call to Lcom/myandroidapps/thegamebase/HomeScreenActivity;.onCreate:VL
06-02 07:46:46.687: I/dalvikvm(2425):   method requires 12+20+8=40 bytes, fp is 0x56d16318 (24 left)
06-02 07:46:46.687: I/dalvikvm(2425):   expanding stack end (0x56d16300 to 0x56d16000)
06-02 07:46:46.687: I/dalvikvm(2425): Shrank stack (to 0x56d16300, curFrame is 0x56d19ec8)
06-02 07:46:46.687: D/AndroidRuntime(2425): Shutting down VM
06-02 07:46:46.687: W/dalvikvm(2425): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40b0a1f8)
06-02 07:46:46.711: D/dalvikvm(2425): GC_CONCURRENT freed 242K, 3% free 11236K/11527K, paused 1ms+1ms
06-02 07:46:46.765: D/dalvikvm(2425): GC_CONCURRENT freed 415K, 5% free 11331K/11847K, paused 2ms+1ms
06-02 07:46:46.781: D/dalvikvm(2425): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 182K, 5% free 11332K/11847K, paused 14ms
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425): java.lang.StackOverflowError
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425):     at com.myandroidapps.thegamefree.HomeScreenActivity.onCreateHomeScreenActivity(Unknown Source)
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425):     at com.myandroidapps.thegamebase.HomeScreenActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425):     at com.myandroidapps.thegamefree.HomeScreenActivity.onCreateHomeScreenActivity(Unknown Source)
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425):     at com.myandroidapps.thegamebase.HomeScreenActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425):     at com.myandroidapps.thegamefree.HomeScreenActivity.onCreateHomeScreenActivity(Unknown Source)
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425):     at com.myandroidapps.thegamebase.HomeScreenActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425):     at com.myandroidapps.thegamefree.HomeScreenActivity.onCreateHomeScreenActivity(Unknown Source)
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425):     at com.myandroidapps.thegamebase.HomeScreenActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425):     at com.myandroidapps.thegamefree.HomeScreenActivity.onCreateHomeScreenActivity(Unknown Source)
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425):     at com.myandroidapps.thegamebase.HomeScreenActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425):     at com.myandroidapps.thegamefree.HomeScreenActivity.onCreateHomeScreenActivity(Unknown Source)
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425):     at com.myandroidapps.thegamebase.HomeScreenActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425):     at com.myandroidapps.thegamefree.HomeScreenActivity.onCreateHomeScreenActivity(Unknown Source)
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425):     at com.myandroidapps.thegamebase.HomeScreenActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425):     at com.myandroidapps.thegamefree.HomeScreenActivity.onCreateHomeScreenActivity(Unknown Source)
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425):     at com.myandroidapps.thegamebase.HomeScreenActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425):     at com.myandroidapps.thegamefree.HomeScreenActivity.onCreateHomeScreenActivity(Unknown Source)
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425):     at com.myandroidapps.thegamebase.HomeScreenActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425):     at com.myandroidapps.thegamefree.HomeScreenActivity.onCreateHomeScreenActivity(Unknown Source)
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425):     at com.myandroidapps.thegamebase.HomeScreenActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425):     at com.myandroidapps.thegamefree.HomeScreenActivity.onCreateHomeScreenActivity(Unknown Source)
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425):     at com.myandroidapps.thegamebase.HomeScreenActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425):     at com.myandroidapps.thegamefree.HomeScreenActivity.onCreateHomeScreenActivity(Unknown Source)
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425):     at com.myandroidapps.thegamebase.HomeScreenActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425):     at com.myandroidapps.thegamefree.HomeScreenActivity.onCreateHomeScreenActivity(Unknown Source)
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425):     at com.myandroidapps.thegamebase.HomeScreenActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425):     at com.myandroidapps.thegamefree.HomeScreenActivity.onCreateHomeScreenActivity(Unknown Source)
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425):     at com.myandroidapps.thegamebase.HomeScreenActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425):     at com.myandroidapps.thegamefree.HomeScreenActivity.onCreateHomeScreenActivity(Unknown Source)
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425):     at com.myandroidapps.thegamebase.HomeScreenActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425):     at com.myandroidapps.thegamefree.HomeScreenActivity.onCreateHomeScreenActivity(Unknown Source)
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425):     at com.myandroidapps.thegamebase.HomeScreenActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425):     at com.myandroidapps.thegamefree.HomeScreenActivity.onCreateHomeScreenActivity(Unknown Source)
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425):     at com.myandroidapps.thegamebase.HomeScreenActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425):     at com.myandroidapps.thegamefree.HomeScreenActivity.onCreateHomeScreenActivity(Unknown Source)
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425):     at com.myandroidapps.thegamebase.HomeScreenActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425):     at com.myandroidapps.thegamefree.HomeScreenActivity.onCreateHomeScreenActivity(Unknown Source)
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425):     at com.myandroidapps.thegamebase.HomeScreenActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425):     at com.myandroidapps.thegamefree.HomeScreenActivity.onCreateHomeScreenActivity(Unknown Source)
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425):     at com.myandroidapps.thegamebase.HomeScreenActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425):     at com.myandroidapps.thegamefree.HomeScreenActivity.onCreateHomeScreenActivity(Unknown Source)
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425):     at com.myandroidapps.thegamebase.HomeScreenActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425):     at com.myandroidapps.thegamefree.HomeScreenActivity.onCreateHomeScreenActivity(Unknown Source)
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425):     at com.myandroidapps.thegamebase.HomeScreenActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425):     at com.myandroidapps.thegamefree.HomeScreenActivity.onCreateHomeScreenActivity(Unknown Source)
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425):     at com.myandroidapps.thegamebase.HomeScreenActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425):     at com.myandroidapps.thegamefree.HomeScreenActivity.onCreateHomeScreenActivity(Unknown Source)
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425):     at com.myandroidapps.thegamebase.HomeScreenActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
06-02 07:46:46.789: E/AndroidRuntime(2425):     at com.myandroidapps.thegam
06-02 07:46:46.805: D/dalvikvm(2425): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 417K, 5% free 11307K/11847K, paused 12ms
06-02 07:46:46.820: D/dalvikvm(2425): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 213K, 5% free 11365K/11847K, paused 11ms
06-02 07:46:46.883: W/ActivityManager(203):   Force finishing activity com.myandroidapps.thegamefree/.HomeScreenActivity
06-02 07:46:46.883: V/ActivityStack(203): Prepare close transition: finishing ActivityRecord{41bfc198 com.myandroidapps.thegamefree/.HomeScreenActivity}
06-02 07:46:46.969: V/PhoneStatusBar(296): setLightsOn(true)
06-02 07:46:46.976: I/WindowManager(203): DIM BEHIND: Window{41c1c3b8 paused=false}
06-02 07:46:46.976: I/WindowManager(203): DIM BEHIND: Window{41c1c3b8 paused=false}
06-02 07:46:47.000: I/WindowManager(203): DIM BEHIND: Window{41c1c3b8 paused=false}
06-02 07:46:47.015: I/WindowManager(203): DIM BEHIND: Window{41c1c3b8 paused=false}
06-02 07:46:47.023: D/dalvikvm(203): GC_CONCURRENT freed 992K, 49% free 16894K/32903K, paused 4ms+8ms
06-02 07:46:47.047: I/WindowManager(203): DIM BEHIND: Window{41c1c3b8 paused=false}
06-02 07:46:47.055: I/WindowManager(203): DIM BEHIND: Window{41c1c3b8 paused=false}
06-02 07:46:47.070: I/WindowManager(203): DIM BEHIND: Window{41c1c3b8 paused=false}
06-02 07:46:47.086: I/WindowManager(203): DIM BEHIND: Window{41c1c3b8 paused=false}
06-02 07:46:47.101: I/WindowManager(203): DIM BEHIND: Window{41c1c3b8 paused=false}
06-02 07:46:47.117: I/WindowManager(203): DIM BEHIND: Window{41c1c3b8 paused=false}
06-02 07:46:47.140: I/WindowManager(203): DIM BEHIND: Window{41c1c3b8 paused=false}
06-02 07:46:47.156: I/WindowManager(203): DIM BEHIND: Window{41c1c3b8 paused=false}
06-02 07:46:47.172: I/WindowManager(203): DIM BEHIND: Window{41c1c3b8 paused=false}
06-02 07:46:47.187: I/WindowManager(203): DIM BEHIND: Window{41c1c3b8 paused=false}
06-02 07:46:47.203: I/WindowManager(203): DIM BEHIND: Window{41c1c3b8 paused=false}
06-02 07:46:47.226: I/WindowManager(203): DIM BEHIND: Window{41c1c3b8 paused=false}
06-02 07:46:47.383: W/ActivityStack(203): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{41bfc198 com.myandroidapps.thegamefree/.HomeScreenActivity}
06-02 07:46:47.383: V/ActivityStack(203): Prepare close transition: prev=ActivityRecord{41bfc198 com.myandroidapps.thegamefree/.HomeScreenActivity}
06-02 07:46:47.383: I/WindowManager(203): DIM BEHIND: Window{41c1c3b8 paused=false}
06-02 07:46:47.390: I/WindowManager(203): DIM BEHIND: Window{41c1c3b8 paused=false}
06-02 07:46:47.555: I/WindowManager(203): DIM BEHIND: Window{41c1c3b8 paused=false}
06-02 07:46:47.562: I/WindowManager(203): DIM BEHIND: Window{41c1c3b8 paused=false}
06-02 07:46:47.578: I/WindowManager(203): DIM BEHIND: Window{41c1c3b8 paused=false}
06-02 07:46:47.594: I/WindowManager(203): DIM BEHIND: Window{41c1c3b8 paused=false}
06-02 07:46:47.609: I/WindowManager(203): DIM BEHIND: Window{41c1c3b8 paused=false}
06-02 07:46:47.625: I/WindowManager(203): DIM BEHIND: Window{41c1c3b8 paused=false}
06-02 07:46:47.648: I/WindowManager(203): DIM BEHIND: Window{41c1c3b8 paused=false}
06-02 07:46:47.664: I/WindowManager(203): DIM BEHIND: Window{41c1c3b8 paused=false}
06-02 07:46:47.680: I/WindowManager(203): DIM BEHIND: Window{41c1c3b8 paused=false}
06-02 07:46:47.695: I/WindowManager(203): DIM BEHIND: Window{41c1c3b8 paused=false}
06-02 07:46:47.703: V/AlarmManager(203): sending alarm Alarm{41a49968 type 0 com.amazon.ags.app}
06-02 07:46:47.711: I/WindowManager(203): DIM BEHIND: Window{41c1c3b8 paused=false}
06-02 07:46:47.726: I/WindowManager(203): DIM BEHIND: Window{41c1c3b8 paused=false}
06-02 07:46:47.750: I/WindowManager(203): DIM BEHIND: Window{41c1c3b8 paused=false}
06-02 07:46:47.765: I/WindowManager(203): DIM BEHIND: Window{41c1c3b8 paused=false}
06-02 07:46:47.781: I/WindowManager(203): DIM BEHIND: Window{41c1c3b8 paused=false}
06-02 07:46:47.797: I/WindowManager(203): DIM BEHIND: Window{41c1c3b8 paused=false}
06-02 07:46:47.820: I/WindowManager(203): DIM BEHIND: Window{41c1c3b8 paused=false}
06-02 07:46:47.836: I/WindowManager(203): DIM BEHIND: Window{41c1c3b8 paused=false}
06-02 07:46:47.851: I/WindowManager(203): DIM BEHIND: Window{41c1c3b8 paused=false}
06-02 07:46:47.867: I/WindowManager(203): DIM BEHIND: Window{41c1c3b8 paused=false}
06-02 07:46:47.883: I/WindowManager(203): DIM BEHIND: Window{41c1c3b8 paused=false}
06-02 07:46:47.906: I/WindowManager(203): DIM BEHIND: Window{41c1c3b8 paused=false}
06-02 07:46:47.922: I/WindowManager(203): DIM BEHIND: Window{41c1c3b8 paused=false}
06-02 07:46:47.945: I/WindowManager(203): DIM BEHIND: Window{41c1c3b8 paused=false}
06-02 07:46:47.953: I/WindowManager(203): DIM BEHIND: Window{41c1c3b8 paused=false}
06-02 07:46:47.976: I/WindowManager(203): DIM BEHIND: Window{41c1c3b8 paused=false}
06-02 07:46:48.086: D/dalvikvm(203): GC_CONCURRENT freed 785K, 47% free 17593K/32903K, paused 2ms+5ms
06-02 07:46:48.289: V/Sensors(203): accel data: 0.011975 -0.119751 10.116563
06-02 07:46:49.945: I/WindowManager(203): DIM BEHIND: Window{41c1c3b8 paused=false}
```

Here is my source for the ad supported HomeScreenActivity:

```
package com.myandroidapps.thegamefree;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class HomeScreenActivity extends com.myandroidapps.thegamebase.HomeScreenActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart)).setOnClickListener(
            new OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    startActivity(new Intent(HomeScreenActivity.this, com.myandroidapps.thegamefree.MainActivity.class));
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

And here is the base class:

```
package com.myandroidapps.thegamebase;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class HomeScreenActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);

        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart)).setOnClickListener(
                new OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        startActivity(new Intent(HomeScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_about)
            startActivity(new Intent(HomeScreenActivity.this, com.myandroidapps.myandroidappslib.AboutActivity.class));
        else if (id == R.id.action_settings)
            startActivity(new Intent(HomeScreenActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class));
        else        
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        return true;
    }

}
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the `onCreateHomeScreenActivity()` method?

Comment: onCreateHomeScreenActivity() is nowhere to be found in my code.

Comment: Well, it's in the call stack, so apparently it exists in the Amazon version. Maybe you removed it later?

Comment: I have checked my repository and that function was definitely never there.  It has always been just the onCreate() function.

Comment: Is it possible that proguard is creating this function name?

Comment: I don't think so, but I don't really know. Sorry.